# How to correctly delete sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection as per Sequelizes documentation?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using typescipt to write an AWS Lambda that connects to a DB through Sequelize.

As per [the official Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/), I should configure Sequelize as:

```
let sequelize = null;

async function loadSequelize() {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* (...) */, {
    // (...)
    pool: {
      /*
       * Lambda functions process one request at a time but your code may issue multiple queries
       * concurrently. Be wary that `sequelize` has methods that issue 2 queries concurrently
       * (e.g. `Model.findAndCountAll()`). Using a value higher than 1 allows concurrent queries to
       * be executed in parallel rather than serialized. Careful with executing too many queries in
       * parallel per Lambda function execution since that can bring down your database with an
       * excessive number of connections.
       *
       * Ideally you want to choose a `max` number where this holds true:
       * max * EXPECTED_MAX_CONCURRENT_LAMBDA_INVOCATIONS < MAX_ALLOWED_DATABASE_CONNECTIONS * 0.8
       */
      max: 2,
      /*
       * Set this value to 0 so connection pool eviction logic eventually cleans up all connections
       * in the event of a Lambda function timeout.
       */
      min: 0,
      /*
       * Set this value to 0 so connections are eligible for cleanup immediately after they're
       * returned to the pool.
       */
      idle: 0,
      // Choose a small enough value that fails fast if a connection takes too long to be established.
      acquire: 3000,
      /*
       * Ensures the connection pool attempts to be cleaned up automatically on the next Lambda
       * function invocation, if the previous invocation timed out.
       */
      evict: CURRENT_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT
    }
  });

  // or `sequelize.sync()`
  await sequelize.authenticate();

  return sequelize;
}

module.exports.handler = async function (event, callback) {
  // re-use the sequelize instance across invocations to improve performance
  if (!sequelize) {
    sequelize = await loadSequelize();
  } else {
    // restart connection pool to ensure connections are not re-used across invocations
    sequelize.connectionManager.initPools();

    // restore `getConnection()` if it has been overwritten by `close()`
    if (sequelize.connectionManager.hasOwnProperty("getConnection")) {
      delete sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection;
    }
  }

  try {
    return await doSomethingWithSequelize(sequelize);
  } finally {
    // close any opened connections during the invocation
    // this will wait for any in-progress queries to finish before closing the connections
    await sequelize.connectionManager.close();
  }
};
```

However this gives the error of:
The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
at `delete sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection;`

How can I correctly delete this?

I'm unsure where to begin with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing exactly the same and it seems that typing the `connectionManager` instance with `getConnection` as optional is working for me (side note: I'm not a TS guru ).

Here my code:

```js
    // restart connection pool to ensure connections are not re-used across invocations
        
    // Workaround: we need to make `getConnection` optional on `ConnectionManager` ts-interface
    // in order to `delete` the property like the docs are recommending for Lambda implementation:
    //   - https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/
    const conxManager: Partial<Pick<ConnectionManager, 'getConnection'>> &
      Omit<ConnectionManager, 'getConnection'> = sequelize.connectionManager;
        
    conxManager.initPools();
        
    // restore `getConnection()` if it has been overwritten by `close()`
    if (isKey(conxManager, 'getConnection')) {
      delete conxManager.getConnection;
    }
```

Below the `isKey` utility function:

```js
function isKey<T extends object>(x: T, k: PropertyKey): k is keyof T {
  return k in x;
}
```

Below the link to the **Sequelize Docs** where it's explained **how to implement this for AWS Lambda**:

- https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/